# Passing data from textarea to the value of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

As you can see in the image I have a textarea and radio buttons.The data is passed to mysql using JSP as the backend.
Once I select a radio button,I need the text from the selected(radio button) editor to pass to the database.
So I would like to know how to pass the text to the value of the radio button,I will post some code of mine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var counter = 1;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>4){
            alert("Only 4 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

//using this new editor gets added
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="radio" name="gointo" id="gointo'+counter'" /><label>Option #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<textarea name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" />');

//ADDED LINE


 if($("#gointo'+counter+'").is(':checked')){
   $("#textbox'+counter+'").val();
 }
```

the form

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="question_form" action="upload"  >
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv0">
        <label>Question: </label><textarea id="textbox0" name="textbox" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
```

Right now with the current code some value `on` gets passed to the database.
Please help

Comment: You're giving the same `id="gointo"` to all the radio buttons. IDs have to be unique, you can't reuse them like this. Do your radio buttons even need IDs? Use a class and iterate over them with jQuery methods.

Comment: Its better I remove the id itself.Dont think its affecting my code at all

Comment: @Barmar I require the ids,my bad for the previous comment.I have this line,where should I add it but
 `if($("#answer'+counter+'").is(':checked')){
       $("#textbox'+counter+'").val();
     }`

Comment: Don't ask me. As you can tell from my answer, I don't understand what you're doing. What is the submit button for if you want to get the textarea value when the radio button is clicked?

Comment: Ok i will explain it to u.suppoose I have a question and 4 options and one answer.so in the database I have 6 columns for all this(question,4options and 1 answer).So I write the 4 options and question using the texxteditor and to select the right answer I use the radio button.and submit the form.@Barmar

Comment: I don't understand why my answer isn't right. When you submit the form, you submit all 4 options, and the value of the radio button is the number of the right answer. All these things go into the database. What do you need Javascript for?

Comment: As you can see in the image above there is canada as the 4th option.And lets suppose canada is selected as the right answer.So in the db ,the columnn for option4 should have `canada` and also the answer column should have `canada`.but in the code you gave me the answer column is 4.Isnt it possible to pass data.This too will work for me

Comment: I don't know JSP, so I didn't give you the server code, I described how you should implement it in generic terms. If you were using PHP, it would be `$answer = $_POST['textbox'.$_POST['gointo']];`, I don't know what that translates to in JSP.

Comment: Can you redesign your database schema? It would be better if yo didn't duplicate the text in the answer column, but just put the choice number there. You should have a table of answers with columns `question#`, `choice#`, `#text`, and the `answer` column in the `questions` table would reference the `choice#` column there.

Comment: Ya i think that will be a gud idea.Thx

Answer (score 2):

Give the radio button a value:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="radio" name="gointo" id="gointo" value="' + counter + '" /><label>Option #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<textarea name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" />');
```

Then your JSP can append the value of the `gointo` parameter to `textbox` to get the name of the appropriate textbox parameter.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to get the value of the textarea when the radio button is clicked, and not the value associated with the radio button

Comment: You have a Submit button, I assumed that everything in the form would be sent to the JSP when you clicked that. The radio button just tells it which textarea's data to put in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
{
document.getElementById("textbox").value = document.getElementById("radiobutton").value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name= "textbox" id="textbox"></textarea>
<input name="x" type="radio" id="radiobutton" value="Cats" onclick="getElements()">Cats
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. I guess you want to collect the value of the textarea when the radio button is clicked. But I guess what you are doing is getting the value of the radio button when it is clicked which would be "ON".

You can get the value of the textarea with something like `$("#textareaid").val()` once you detect that radio button has been clicked.

Something like below should work for you :-

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')){
   $("#textareaid").val();
 }
```

Comment: How to do it.I am bad at javascript and jquery

Comment: Should I add it in a seperate script ?

Comment: @Vidic replace #radio_button with your radiobutton id and #textarea with your textareaid

Comment: @Vidic  Sorry! I guess you will have to figure out yourself from here... :-)

Comment: I added your line.check my edit above.But still gives me some unknown value `on`